# Get a vertical line to run down the page

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical line running down the middle of my page, but it only goes as far as the first section. What I want it to do is run all the way down to the very end of the page when you scroll all the way down. I'm not sure how to achieve this.
Right now my CSS for my line is this:

```
.line{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px dotted black;
  }
```

I don't want to have a set height, because as I start adding more projects to the site, I would like the line to grow with the page without having to change the height every time.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/Furr/pen/gJLapb

This website is my inspiration, I would like it to be something like this: https://www.rezo-zero.com/projects/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may actually want 3 divs like this. ( the line is a div)

```css
.vl {
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
  height: 500px;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#right {
  width: 300px;
      margin-left: 5px;

}
#left {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">Left Side</div>
  <div class="vl"></div>
  <div id="right">Right Side</div>
</div>
```

another reason to have 3 divs is that you can "break up" the line with clickable content just like in your example

Comment: Can you explain why I need two divs? And this has a set height, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: there may be other ways to do what you are wanting to do, but when I first saw the site, my best guess was to use two divs so you would have content on both sides of the vertical line.

Comment: height: auto; may fix the height issue

Answer (score 0):

One of feasible way is to use pseudo element to make the vertical line so that it will expand according to the container. Here is an simple example.

```css
.timeline-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.timeline-container:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.timeline-container .event {
  width: 50%;
}
.timeline-container .event.left {
  text-align: right;
}
.timeline-container .event.right {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.timeline-container .event-content {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-container">
  <div class="event left">
    <div class="event-content">2019-05-14<br>Testing Events</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event right">
    <div class="event-content">2019-05-10<br>Another Events</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event left">
    <div class="event-content">2019-04-25<br>Great Exhibition</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event right">
    <div class="event-content">2019-03-27<br>School Festival</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can look at the source code for the website you wanted to emulate by typing CTRL + SHIFT + I in Chrome after opening it.